# How can I toggle this dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried adding a simple toggle function to the dropdown-btn class which in turn adds the active class (which is set to display: block;) onto the ul class, am I doing anything wrong here?

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-btn');

dropdown.addEventListener('click', function() {
  dropdown.classList.toggle('active');

});
```

```css
.sidebar-nav {
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  background: #f0f7ff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 150ms ease;
  position: relative;
}

.options {
  display: none;
}

.options.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="admin-sidebar sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-btn"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i><span>Dropdown</span>     <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
    <ul class="options">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<nav/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the button you have to toggle the active class on the `ul` element, wich you have set `display:none` .

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-btn');
const options  = document.querySelector('.options');

dropdown.addEventListener('click', function() {
  options.classList.toggle('active');

});
```

```css
.sidebar-nav {
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  background: #f0f7ff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 150ms ease;
  position: relative;
}

.options {
  display: none;
}

.options.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="admin-sidebar sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-btn"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i><span>Dropdown</span><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
    <ul class="options">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <nav/>
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, I see my mistake now, so I had not targeted the ul, I feel very silly. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your function and then change the event to focus and then create another function by blur and change display to none bro :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('optioons').style.display = 'block';
```